# List of TestNG Groups

Tags: testng

does anyone here have a good way to list all TestNG groups used in a project? The simplest way that comes to my mind is `grep groups *.java`. But these would not be unique. Any other ideas?

Regards,
Robin

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you want to do it. Since you mention `grep`, I'm guessing you want to use the shell, so `uniq` will remove duplicates. In Java, simple introspection of your test classes will give you all your groups.